# AG Grid React Chart Toolbar not displaying Chart toolbar

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We've recently gone through an upgrade of ag-grid-react to version 23.0.0 and have enabled charting, but I've noticed that we don't have the chart toolbar rendered under the hamburger menu as it would be in the demos. I've imported/configured the grid as follows:

```js
import 'ag-grid-enterprise/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham-dark.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

// ... component definition things as referenced in props below

<AgGridReact
  defaultColDef={columnDefs.defaultColDef}
  columnTypes={columnDefs.columnTypes}
  columnDefs={cols}
  rowData={rows.length ? rows : null}
  enableRangeSelection
  groupMultiAutoColumn
  groupDefaultExpanded={2}
  groupHideOpenParents
  suppressAggFuncInHeader
  resizable
  sortable
  animateRows
  pivotMode={prefs.pivotMode}
  suppressLoadingOverlay
  statusBar={this.state.statusBar}
  onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
  autoGroupColumnDef={{ cellRendererParams: { suppressCount: true } }}
  getContextMenuItems={this.getContextMenuItems}
  enableCharts
/>
```

Screenshot of result: The toolbar renders, [but we don't have the menu to change data/settings along the right hand side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ibRs.png) that are found in the [Documentation and demos](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-charts-integrated-chart-toolbar/). I'm not sure if I'm missing something in the configuration of the grid, or if I'm missing some chart-specific imports. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on my own, in our package.json there was a conflicting style included from an older ag-grid that was conflicting with the styles